# calling spark-ec2 from within an EC2 instance: ssh connection to host refused

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, apache-spark

In order to run Amplab's training exercises, I've create a keypair on `us-east-1` , have installed the training scripts (`git clone git://github.com/amplab/training-scripts.git -b ampcamp4`) and created the env. variables AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY following the instructions in http://ampcamp.berkeley.edu/big-data-mini-course/launching-a-bdas-cluster-on-ec2.html

Now running

```
 ./spark-ec2 -i ~/.ssh/myspark.pem -r us-east-1  -k myspark --copy launch try1
```

generates the following messages:

```
 johndoe@ip-some-instance:~/projects/spark/training-scripts$ ./spark-ec2 -i ~/.ssh/myspark.pem -r us-east-1  -k myspark --copy launch try1
 Setting up security groups...
 Searching for existing cluster try1...
 Latest Spark AMI: ami-19474270
 Launching instances...
 Launched 5 slaves in us-east-1b, regid = r-0c5e5ee3
 Launched master in us-east-1b, regid = r-316060de
 Waiting for instances to start up...
 Waiting 120 more seconds...
 Copying SSH key /home/johndoe/.ssh/myspark.pem to master...
 ssh: connect to host ec2-54-90-57-174.compute-1.amazonaws.com port 22: Connection refused
 Error connecting to host Command 'ssh -t -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i /home/johndoe/.ssh/myspark.pem root@ec2-54-90-57-174.compute-1.amazonaws.com 'mkdir -p ~/.ssh'' returned  non-zero exit status 255, sleeping 30
 ssh: connect to host ec2-54-90-57-174.compute-1.amazonaws.com port 22: Connection refused
 Error connecting to host Command 'ssh -t -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i /home/johndoe/.ssh/myspark.pem root@ec2-54-90-57-174.compute-1.amazonaws.com 'mkdir -p ~/.ssh'' returned non-zero exit status 255, sleeping 30
 ...
 ...
 subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'ssh -t -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i /home/johndoe/.ssh/myspark.pem root@ec2-54-90-57-174.compute-1.amazonaws.com '/root/spark/bin/stop-all.sh'' returned non-zero exit status 127
```

where `root@ec2-54-90-57-174.compute-1.amazonaws.com` is the user & master instance. I've tried `-u ec2-user` and increasing `-w` all the way up to 600, but get the same error.

I can see the master and slave instances in `us-east-1` when I log into the AWS console, and I can actually ssh into the Master instance from the 'local' `ip-some-instance` shell.

My understanding is that the spark-ec2 script takes care of defining the Master/Slave security groups (which ports are listened to and so on), and I shouldn't have to tweak these settings. This said, master and slaves all listen to post 22 (`Port:22, Protocol:tcp, Source:0.0.0.0/0` in the ampcamp3-slaves/masters sec. groups).

I'm at a loss here, and would appreciate any pointers before I spend all my R&D funds on EC2 instances.... Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is most likely caused by SSH taking a long time to start up on the instances, causing the 120 second timeout to expire before the machines could be logged into.  You should be able to run

```
./spark-ec2 -i ~/.ssh/myspark.pem -r us-east-1  -k myspark --copy launch --resume try1
```

(with the `--resume` flag) to continue from where things left off without re-launching new instances.  This issue will be fixed in Spark 1.2.0, where we have a new mechanism that intelligently checks the SSH status rather than relying on a fixed timeout.  We're also addressing the root causes behind the long SSH startup delay by building new AMIs.

Comment: Thanks. Still not getting access to the cluster, maybe I have to wait longer (it's already been 1.5hrs so I assume there's something else at work).

Comment: `Exception in opening the url http://ec2-54-90-57-174.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080/json
Error connecting to host Command 'ssh -t -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i /home/johndoe/.ssh/myspark.pem root@ec2-54-90-57-174.compute-1.amazonaws.com '/root/spark/bin/stop-all.sh'' returned non-zero exit status 127, sleeping 30`

Comment: Which version of Spark are you using?

Comment: Indeed, the 1.2.0 version of Spark (released on 18/12/14) deprecates the "waiting" flag and automatically waits for instances to be in a 'ssh-ready' state.