# Spark long deploying time on EC2 with custom Windows AMI

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, apache-spark

I am trying to run a Spark cluster with some *Windows* instances on an *Amazon EC2* infrastructure, but I am facing some issues with extremely high deploying times.

My project needs to be run on a *Windows* environment, and therefore I am using an alternative AMI by indicating it with the `-a` flag provided by *Spark*'s `spark-ec2` script. When I run the script, the process keeps stuck waiting for the instances to be up and running, with the following message:

```
Waiting for all instances in cluster to enter 'ssh-ready' state.............
```

When I use the default AMI, instead, the cluster launches normally after very few minutes of waiting.

I have searched for similar problems with other users, and so far I have only been able to find [this statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26832980/calling-spark-ec2-from-within-an-ec2-instance-ssh-connection-to-host-refused/26834401#comment44117081_26834401) about *long deploying time with custom AMI-s* (see Josh Rosen's answer).

I am using the version 1.2.0 of *Spark*. The call that launches the cluster looks something like the following:

```
./spark-ec2 -k MyKeyPair 
            -i MyKeyPair.pem 
            -s 10 
            -a ami-905fe9e7
            --instance-type=t1.micro 
            --region=eu-west-1
            --spark-version=1.2.0
            launch MyCluster
```

The *AMI* indicated above refers to:

```
Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 Base - ami-905fe9e7
Desc: Microsoft Windows 2012 R2 Standard edition with 64-bit architecture. [English]
```

Any help or acclaration abouth this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For what it's worth, I see extremely long "waiting for ssh-ready" times as well, with the default (Linux) AMI. Don't know what's wrong.

Comment: I had specified the wrong path for the key file. Apparently the script treats _any_ error from SSH as "the cluster is probably not up yet". Can you manually SSH into the machines?

Comment: I already answered the question. It was my fault not to see that Spark's `spark-ec2` script does not work on a *Windows* environment. Anyway, thanks for the tips, the error could easily be created from a simple error like that.

Comment: @DanielDarabos - We fixed this as part of [SPARK-5473](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-5473) so that such errors bubble up to the user. Should be in for Spark 1.2.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I have figured out the problem. It seems *Spark* does not support the creation of clusters on a *Windows* environment with its default scripts. I think it is still possible to create a cluster with some manual tweaking, but it goes out of my limited knowledge. [Here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/spark-standalone.html) is the official post that explains it.

Instead, as a temporal solution, I am considering the usage of a *Microsoft Azure* cluster, which has just released an experimental tool that makes able to use a variant of *Apache Hadoop (Spark)* on their *HDinsight* clusters. [Here](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/11/17/azure-hdinsight-clusters-can-now-be-customized-to-run-a-variety-of-hadoop-projects-including-spark-and-r/) is the article that explains it better.